# Knockout observablearray will not accept item updated with value from server

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, data-binding, knockout.js, ko.observablearray

I have an item list displayed with knockout binding. Simplified it looks something like this:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: currentItems ">
    <li>
        <div>
            <span data-bind="text: Heading"></span>
        </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

In a select list I have potential items that can be added to the first list. When a value is double-clicked an ajax call is initiated with the selectedItem.

```
<select id="lstSongs" data-bind="options: possibleItems, optionsText: 'Heading', value: selectedItem, dblclick: $root.addItem"></select>
```

Both arrays use the same model structure defined on server.

The viewmodel looks like this:

```
function MyViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.currentItems = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.possibleItems = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.selectedItem = ko.observable();

    self.addItem = function(item) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/api/MyController/AddItem",
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            data: ko.toJSON(item),
            success: function(itemId) {

                // Attempt1
                alert(itemId);
                item.ItemId(itemId);
                alert("hello1");
                alert(item.ItemId);
                currentItems.push(item);

                // Attempt2
                alert(itemId);
                item.ItemId = itemId;
                alert("hello2");
                alert(item.ItemId);
                currentItems.push(item);

                // Attempt3
                alert(itemId);
                selectedItem.ItemId = itemId;
                alert("hello3");
                alert(selectedItem.ItemId);
                currentItems.push(selectedItem);
            }
        });
    };
}

var viewModel = new MyViewModel();
var data = @Html.Raw(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model));
ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, viewModel);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

The list with currentItems is loaded from the MVC initial model with ko.mapping. The possibleItems is loaded with values from a dynamic ajax call. But both are loaded as expected so I think those bindings are OK.

The doubleclick is triggered as expected. The call is detected at server and an appropriate itemId is returned. On successful return that value should be set on the selectedItem. Then the selectedItem should be added to the currentItems array and turn up in the first list.

I have elaborated with several attempts but without success. I tried them one at the time with the others commented.

Attempt1: The itemId is returned but the first hello is not reached. Why? Is that not the way to set observable properties?

Attempt2: The value is set, hello2 displayed and itemId reported to be set. But the push call does not make the item turn up in the currentItem list.

Attempt3: The same approach but this time the property is set on the the viewModel selectedItem. This time the hello3 is not reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bradley Trager got me on the right track with his first suggestion. To maybe help someone else I just add the working solution here:

```
var addedItem = ko.mapping.fromJSON(ko.toJSON(item));
addedItem.ItemId(itemId);
self.currentItems.push(addedItem);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your first attempt isn't working because `item` is probably not being passed as an observable but a value.

Your second attempt should work fine, but you need to use the `self` variable:

```
self.currentItems.push(item);
```

Your third attempt isn't working for the same reason as attempt one.

Comment: Thanks, this sounded promising, but does not work. Any other suggestion along the ko.mapping track?

Comment: Your last suggestion does not work, but the first suggestion you had got me on the right track! You should not change your answer. Rather add new information in answer or in comments. If you add your previous answer back I will gladly give you credit for it. By first converting the item object to json string and THEN use ko.mapping to generate it into an observable object I made it all work beautiful! Thanks for good help! Please see working code in separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create an instance of your added item and assign it to you selectedItem and currentItems array accordingly

```
success: function() {    
    var addedItem = new Item {ItemId:item.ItemId,Heading:item.Heading };
    self.selectedItem(addedItem);
    self.currentItems.push(addedItem);
    alert("Successfully added");   
}
```

Comment: Hi, your answer has automatically been added to the Low Quality Posts review queue. You could substantially improve your answer (and increase your chances of earning upvotes!) if you edited to explain this code snippet. :)

Comment: It sounds a bit clumsy to copy every property of a an observable object where only one property is missing .... But if it works I am willing to do it. As mentioned all data in my view model is generated from model coming from MVC controller. So the object is not really defined in the view model. I guess this means I can not use the constructor "new Item"? Is it possible to use anonymous typing? I tried "var addeItem = new {ItemId: ... }" but it does not work. Do I have to rip my whole setup and define the object structure in view model? Not nice.

Answer (score 0):

I think I can [reproduce](http://jsfiddle.net/A29tP/) your issue. Seems to me your problem is that you're databinding to the (double) click of the *`select`*, where you would like to trigger the event on *`option`s* instead. You can see this if you don't `alert(itemId)` but instead `console.log(item)`: it's the root viewmodel that's being passed to your function.

Two solutions come to mind:

- Use a custom binding handler that finds the actual clicked element (upon skimming similar to [this approach](http://lonetechie.com/2012/10/02/knockout-js-and-select-options-binding-pre-selection/)); or
- Drop the `select` and use a list with individually templated items ("options") that each have a `dblclick` binding.